# Scala REPL "paste" mode doesn't exit on ctrl-D in Sublime Text 2

Tags: scala, sublimetext2, read-eval-print-loop, sublimerepl

Has anyone seen this problem? Start the scala REPL and

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val x = 5
```

ctrl-D does not cause REPL to finish paste mode.

Comment: This is scala 2.10.1, Sublime Text 2 and Mac OS X 10.8.3

Comment: I assume you're using SublimeREPL?

Comment: so it seems that Sublime is grabbing the ctrl-D for its multiedit

Comment: I guess he hasn't seen it here, so head over to GitHub and open an [issue](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues). The author of SublimeREPL is quite nice and usually pretty responsive to questions. I seem to recall that some commands like this had a different modifier key for another REPL, but I can't find the documentation anywhere...

Answer (score 9):

Just insert a new line (ENTER) after u paste then hit CTRL-D. Spent a half an hour to figure this out